# Featuretools relationship with non unique join key

Tags: python, feature-extraction, feature-engineering, featuretools

Assuming I have two tables, one with metadata about a customer with field `customer_id` and an events table recorded from website clickstream events with fields `customer_id`, `date`. Obviously, the second table might have several non unique events (unfortunately date is really only a date not a timestamp).

When trying to create https://docs.featuretools.com/loading_data/using_entitysets.html it fails with:

```
Index is not unique on dataframe (Entity transactions)
```

How can I either make it unique or make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your table doesn't have a column that can be used as an unique index, you can have featuretools automatically create one. When calling `EntitySet.entity_from_dataframe(...)` simply provide a column name that doesn't currently exist in the dataframe to the `index` parameter and set `make_index=True`. This will automatically create a column with unique values.

For example, in the code below the `event_id` index is automatically created

```
import pandas as pd
import featuretools as ft

df = pd.DataFrame({"customer_id": [0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
                   "date": [pd.Timestamp("1/1/2018"), pd.Timestamp("1/1/2018"),
                            pd.Timestamp("1/1/2018"), pd.Timestamp("1/2/2018"),
                            pd.Timestamp("1/2/2018")],
                   "event_type": ["view", "purchase", "view", "cancel", "purchase"]})

es = ft.EntitySet(id="customer_events")                
es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id="events",
                         dataframe=df,
                         index="event_id",
                         make_index=True,
                         time_index="date")

print(es["events"])
```

in the events entity you can see event_id is now a variable even though it wasn't in the original dataframe

```
Entity: events
  Variables:
    event_id (dtype: index)
    date (dtype: datetime_time_index)
    customer_id (dtype: numeric)
    event_type (dtype: categorical)
  Shape:
    (Rows: 5, Columns: 4)
```